# Force reloading of the javascript

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I've modified the js of `lightbox` and I don't know how to do it for other browsers to load for the new version. On my machine I did `Ctrl-F5` but I don't know how to do that for visitors browsers. I was thinking that I can modify the file name of the `.js`, but this is not a clean&fair approach.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);

<script src="lightbox.js?randomNumber"></script>
```

It should force the browser to go and download the latest version of the js file at every page refresh.

Comment: most people use a version number, to force the web browser to reload the file. randomNumber = version_number

Comment: @IdanHen: very good approach. pls add it as a diferent answer in order to choose it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try sending from your sevrer of configuration the version_number .

```
<script src="lightbox.js?version_number"></script>
```